# Comparing Kronecker pairings for different coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Assume $C_*$ is a chain complex of free $R$-modules where $R$ is a ring.

Following [Davis, Kirk, Lecture Notes in Algebraic Topology, Exercise 11 - p. 14], we can define then a $\textit{Kronecker pairing}$ $\langle \hspace{0.25cm}, \hspace{0.22cm}\rangle_R$ in the following way:
$$
\langle \hspace{0.25cm}, \hspace{0.22cm}\rangle_R:H^k(C_*;R)\times H_k(C_*;R)\longrightarrow R
$$ 
$$
\langle[\varphi],[\Sigma]\rangle_R=\varphi(\Sigma),
$$
where $k\in\{0,\ldots,\}$ and $H^k(C_*;R)$, $H_k(C_*;R)$ are $k$-th cohomology and comology of $C_*$ with coefficients in $R$ respectively and $\varphi\in C^k(C_*;R)$, $\Sigma\in C_k(C_*;R)$.

Let $k\geq 0$ and $\varphi\in C^k(C_*;\mathbb{Z})$, $\Sigma\in C_k(C_*;\mathbb{Z})$.

For $n\geq 2$ define $\varphi_n\in C^k(C_*;\mathbb{Z}_n)$ and $\Sigma_n\in C_k(C_*;\mathbb{Z}_n)$ as follows
$$
\varphi_n(x)=\varphi(x)(\bmod n),
$$
$$
\Sigma_n=\Sigma\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}b,
$$
where $b$ is the generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Is it true that
$$
\langle[\varphi_n],[\Sigma_n]\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}_n}=\langle[\varphi],[\Sigma]\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}}(\bmod n)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter example. (Or at least something to think about.) Let $K$ be the Klein bottle. Then $H_2(K, \mathbb{Z})=0$ and $H^{2}(K,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus the pairing here is zero.

However, $H_2(K, \mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ ( as the Klein bottle is orientable mod $2$) and $H^{2}(K,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$. And you can convince yourself that the pairing here is nontrivial.

Comment: Yeah. It works. What about if we assume that $C_*$ is a chain complex of an orientable manifold?